# Panels Everywhere and missing Page Title

Tags: panels

I am new to using Panels Everywhere and noticed that once I applied PE to my site the page titles went missing. I have site name and slogan and such set up. I can't figure out where the problem is. Has anyone run across this before?

Answer (score 1):

I think page title is a pane you can add to your PE master.

In the region you want to put it:

Add content -> Page elements -> Page title